# Synonymize tags [secure-erase] and [secure-delete]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Well, [secure-erase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/secure-erase) and [secure-delete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/secure-delete) simply mean the same, so we should synonymize them.

Here some stats about those two:

#### [secure-erase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/secure-erase):

- 13 questions
- 0 followers
- Excerpt: *none*
- Wiki: *none*

#### [secure-delete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/secure-delete):

- 11 questions
- 0 followers
- Excerpt: *none*
- Wiki: *none*

As @MarkKirby said, the phrase "secure delete" does not make too much sense, because "delete" usually means removing the reference while only "erase" means to truly nuke the object.

Therefore the best would be to automatically retag all [secure-delete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/secure-delete) questions to [secure-erase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/secure-erase).

Comment: I don't think they are the same, here is a good quote I took from a site on the difference between `delete` and `erase` "in the technological world deleting only refers to removing the object, but the evidence of that object is still there. However, erasing refers to completely wiping it out meaning it is not longer available or recoverable." IMO they are related but different words.

Comment: @MarkKirby There might be that difference between "delete" and "erase", but if you say "secure-delete" I say it means the same again.

Comment: Well, in spite of my first comment, looking around at what people say about this, it seems `secure-delete` may actually be a bit of a misnomer. I would be for re tagging all the questions as `secure-erase` and just do away with `secure-delete`, so I do support this, as the `secure-delete` tag is a bit pointless.

Comment: @MarkKirby I guess I can agree with that, but, it new questions should also automatically get retagged if somebody tries to use "secure-delete".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done. Merged `secure-delete` into `secure-erase` and created a synonym between the two.

```
updating post history, 12 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 11 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 10 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [secure-erase] and [secure-delete] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym secure-delete -> secure-erase was approved!
```